# primefaces p:commandButton update property fails to update p:messages component

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2

I have a PrimeFaces `<p:commandButton update=":messages"` which doesn't display `p:messages` after sending the form, but if I use `update="@all"` instead it does update `p:messages` and I can see the messages displayed.

I've tried many other combinations such as `update="messages"`, `update="NewRegistryForm:messages"`, `update="@form :messages"`, `render=":messages"`... but nothing else seems to work. Any idea why this might be happening?

On `RegistryInputNewBean.processRequest` I simply update the messages component like this:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(
    null,
    new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "", "error_processing_request")
);
```

`mytemplate.xhtml`, containing  `p:messages`, is something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    lang="en"
>
    <f:view contentType="text/html" encoding="UTF-8" locale="en">
        <h:head>
            <title>test</title>
        </h:head>
        <h:body id="pageBody">
            <p:messages id="messages" showDetail="true" autoUpdate="true" closable="true" showSummary="false"/>
            <ui:insert name="content" />
        </h:body>
    </f:view>
</html>
```

`myform.xhtml` is like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" 
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" 
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" 
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
>
<ui:define name="content">
<ui:composition template="mytemplate.xhtml">
        <h:form id="NewRegistryForm">
                <p:commandButton 
                    id="sendButton"
                    type="submit" 
                    action="#{registryInputNewBean.processRequest}" 
                    update="@all"
                    style="display:none" />
        </h:form>
</ui:composition>
</ui:define>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `p:messages` is not inside a form, that is why the button is not going to update the component alone, only if you put `@all`, which refresh all the components in the page.

If you put another form that contain the `p:message` inside, you will be able to update the component with an `update="fooForm:fooMessages"`

Answer (score 1):

you can update on the bean

Like

```
RequestContext rc = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
rc.update("id");
```

Comment: Yes you could, but would that result in different behavior than using `update` on a `p:commandButton`?